# java.lang.RuntimeException Caused by: retrofit.RetrofitError: com.squareup.okhttp.Request$Builder

Tags: java, android, image, retrofit, put

I'm using RetroFit version 1.9.0 to make a PUT request to add an image to a location while also using an access cookie, but before the image transfer even begins proper, I get the error:

```
09-14 13:35:12.718  21896-22689/com.company.app E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #5
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
        at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
 Caused by: retrofit.RetrofitError: com.squareup.okhttp.Request$Builder
        at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler.invokeRequest(RestAdapter.java:400)
        at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler.invoke(RestAdapter.java:240)
        at $Proxy10.addPicture(Native Method)
        at com.company.app.parser.ImageSender$BackgroundTask.doInBackground(ImageSender.java:70)
        at com.company.app.parser.ImageSender$BackgroundTask.doInBackground(ImageSender.java:39)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
 Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.squareup.okhttp.Request$Builder
        at retrofit.client.OkClient.createRequest(OkClient.java:57)
        at retrofit.client.OkClient.execute(OkClient.java:53)
        at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler.invokeRequest(RestAdapter.java:326)
        at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler.invoke(RestAdapter.java:240)
        at $Proxy10.addPicture(Native Method)
        at com.company.app.parser.ImageSender$BackgroundTask.doInBackground(ImageSender.java:70)
        at com.company.app.parser.ImageSender$BackgroundTask.doInBackground(ImageSender.java:39)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

This is how the request is made:

```
private class BackgroundTask extends AsyncTask<TypedFile, Void, JSONObject> {

    RestAdapter restAdapter;

    RequestInterceptor requestInterceptor = new RequestInterceptor() {
        @Override
        public void intercept(RequestInterceptor.RequestFacade request) {
            request.addHeader("Cookie", CookieJar.openJar().getCookie());
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
                .setEndpoint(BasicData.BASE_URL)
                .setRequestInterceptor(requestInterceptor)
                .setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL)
                .build();
    }

    @Override
    protected JSONObject doInBackground(TypedFile... params) {
        IApiMethods methods = restAdapter.create(IApiMethods.class);
        JSONObject response = methods.addPicture(CardManager.getInstance().getCurrentCard().getId(), params[0]);

        return response;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject response) {
        if (response != null) {
            parserReceiver.parseSuccess(null, parserName);
        }
    }
}
```

Stuff

```
public interface IApiMethods {

  @Headers({
        "Connection: Keep-Alive"
  })
  @Multipart
  @PUT("/0.1/ideas/{id}/picture")
  JSONObject addPicture(@Path("id") String ideaId, @Part("file") TypedFile picture);
}
```

Comment: I'm using version 1.9.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe Retrofit may require the OkHttp dependency

`compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.2.0'`

Comment: I feel kinda dumb as looking at it now it was kind of in my face, but since I don't think I've seen it mentioned anywhere in their documentation, I failed to notice. Thank you nonetheless, this has been giving me trouble for a couple days now!